# Escaping space character in yaml sequence of strings in helm

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm using `helm template` command to template a file but cannot escape a space character in yaml sequence. I have tried with `""` and `''` but the result remains the same.

**template.yaml:**

```
scriptsApproval:
{{ toYaml .Values.scriptApproval }}
```

**values.yaml:**

```
scriptsApproval:
- string1 abc ijk lmn
- string2 abc ijk lmn
- string3 abc ijk lmn
```

Getting Results after running `helm template`

**result.yaml:**

```
scriptsApproval:
- string1 abc ijk 
  lmn
- string2 abc ijk 
  lmn
- string3 abc ijk 
  lmn
```

Comment: Is that your actual input and output?  I don't see that behavior if I try to copy and run this (and spell the variable name consistently) and that's not the way I'd expect Helm to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Helm's `|quote` function described [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#quote-strings-dont-quote-integers) and [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#formatting-templates)

```
{{ toYaml .Values.scriptApproval }}
```

Would be something like

```
{{ range .Values.scriptApproval }}
{{ . | quote }}
{{ end }}
```

*Untested